# ZSH autocomplete function using existing autocompletions

Tags: autocomplete, zsh, zsh-completion

I have a function `mycmd` to launch a program that I wrote. The program needs the first argument to be `foo`, `ssh` or `ls`. The second argument depends on the first argument as follows,

1. `foo` -> No second argument
2. `ssh` -> Something to ssh to
3. `ls` -> A file

I want to write zsh autocomplete function for `mycmd` which suggest the second argument depending on the first argument. In the simplest form, I know that I can do the following for the first argument

```
_mycmd() {
    compadd foo ssh ls
}
compdef _mycmd mycmd
```

I have a hard time understanding what to do for the second argument from here. How do I use `_ssh` autocomplete for `ssh` argument and `_ls` autocomplete for `ls` argument? (And nothing for `foo` as well)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To inspect the current command line, it could be used [`$words`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Completion-Widgets.html#index-words) and [`$CURRENT`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Completion-Widgets.html#index-CURRENT) that are the completion special parameters.

> [`CURRENT`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Completion-Widgets.html#index-CURRENT)
> This is the number of the current word, i.e. the word the cursor is currently  on in the words array.
> ...
> [`words`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Completion-Widgets.html#index-words)
> This array contains the words present on the command line curently being edited.
>
> --- [zshcompwid(1), completion special parameters, zshcompwid - zsh completion widgets](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Completion-Widgets.html#Completion-Special-Parameters)

The completion function could modify `$words` and `$CURRENT` (and/or other variables) and then start the entire completion system based with its modified command line. For example:

```
$ mycmd ls -al<TAB>               ;# This is the input, and
;# $words == ("mycmd" "ls" "-al") ;# original value for $words.
;# $words=("ls" "-al")            ;# We could update $words for making zsh
;# $ ls -al<TAB>                  ;# to start the completion system with
                                  ;# its modified command line.
                                  ;# Finally, _ls would be called.
```

The utility function [`_normal`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-_005fnormal) could be used.

> [`_normal`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-_005fnormal)
> ...
> A second use is to reexamine the command line specified by the `$words` array and the `$CURRENT` parameter after those have been modified.
>
> -- [zshcompsys(1), utility function, _normal](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-_005fnormal)

`_mycmd` could be listed below:

```
_mycmd () {
  if ((CURRENT == 2)); then
    compadd foo ssh ls
  elif ((CURRENT > 2)); then
    case "$words[2]" in
      (ssh|ls)
        shift words
        ((CURRENT--))
        _normal -p mycmd
        ;;
      (foo)
        _nothing
        ;;
      (*)
        _message "mycmd: invalid subcommand or arguments"
        ;;
    esac
  fi
  return $?
}
```

or even, more use of the completion builtin/utility functions like below:

```
_mycmd () {
  local curcontext="${curcontext}" state context line
  local -A opt_args
  _arguments '*:: :->subcmd'
  if [[ "$state" == "subcmd" ]]; then
    if ((CURRENT == 1)); then
      _describe -t mycmd-subcmd "mycmd command" '(foo ssh ls)'
    else
      curcontext="${curcontext%:*:*}:mycmd-$words[1]:"
      case "$words[1]" in
        (ssh|ls)
          compset -n 1
          _normal -p $service
        ;;
        (foo)
          _nothing
        ;;
        (*)
          _message "mycmd: invalid subcommand or arguments"
        ;;
      esac
    fi
  fi
  return $?
}
```